# $_POST var not populated instead $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA takes data

Tags: php, html, json, forms, file

i use this function in `javascript` to communicate with the server php script:

```
    ajax = function( url, ready, json=null, method = 'post') {
    var response, request = xhr();
    request.open( method, url, true );
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( request.readyState == 4 ) {
            if( typeof ready == 'function' ){
                return ready( request );
            } else {    return JSON.parse( request.responseText );}
        } 
    }
    if(json !== null){
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        return request.send( JSON.stringify( json ) );
    }else { return request.send( null );}
}
```

i made the `XMLHttpRequest` after i open the connection using `post method`.
i also set the `setRequestHeader` to parse `JSON: ("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");` and i used this function to colect `data` from `html form`:

```
formToValues = function (id) {
    var i, values = {}, form = document.getElementById(id);
    //var fields = form.querySelectorAll('input,textarea,select'),
    for (i = 0; i < form.length ;i++) {
        if( form.elements[i].name !== "" ){
            values[form.elements[i].name] = form.elements[i].value;
        }
    }
    return values;
}


ajax('a.php', function(response){
    console.log(response);
}, formToValues("regForm") );
```

here is also my `html form`:

```
<form id="regForm" action="javascript:;" method="post" />
<p>
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="xhr" />

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" value="ro@ew.gq" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="pass" />

<input type="button" value="Search" />
</p>
```

now i have a liitle problem reciving data in `php` script:
`a.php`:

```
<?php
var_dump(  $GLOBALS );
$ar= array( "a"=>2,"b"=>3, "c"=>json_decode( $_REQUEST['params'] ));
echo json_encode($ar);
?>
```

seems like php take my data sended from javascrip as string and store it in `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`

`["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]=>
    string(51) "{"name":"xhr","email":"ro@ew.gq","password":"pass"}"`

```
    "array(7) {
  ["GLOBALS"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["GLOBALS"]=>
    *RECURSION*
    ["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]=>
    string(51) "{"name":"xhr","email":"ro@ew.gq","password":"pass"}"
    ["_POST"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_GET"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_COOKIE"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_FILES"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_REQUEST"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

now i can get data with  `php://input` will not be a problem but i am concernet about security and it dos'n sems ok, and it's one more thing to get in consideration : starting with php version 5.6.0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA — Raw POST data is deprecated~ so what should i do? 
Tkanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not populate the $_POST superglobal when the request content type is `application/json` (only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`).

The suggestion is to use `json_decode()` and `php://input`.